# How to disable WowJS animations from occuring more than once?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations, wow.js

I have a webpage with a bunch of WowJS animations. The animations occur when I scroll down, which is fine. However, when I scroll back up, the animations occur again. How can I disable the animations occurring more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you scroll back up it, it will not do a animation again default behaviour of WowJs. WowJs library does not provide functionality like when you scroll back up animation will apply.(means wowJs Reset option is not available.animation never apply more than once in wowJs Library).